# Почему onclick не срабатывает на динамическом элементе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть динамический элемент:

```
<script id="bank-deposit-row" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="row table-row bank-deposit-row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 table-col">${closing_balance_date}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 table-col">Deposit ${statement_id}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 table-col">${account_currency}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 table-col">${closing_balance_amount - opening_balance_amount}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 table-col"></div>
</div>
```

С помощью `jQuery.tmpl` на страницу добавляются блоки из  `<script>`, в js файле есть функция, которая отрабатывает по клику:

```
$('.bank-deposit-row').on('click', function() {
alert("Onclick is working!");
$('.reconciliation-modal').show();
$('.cit-pickup-row').draggable({
    revert:"invalid",
    drag: function(event, ui){
        window.dragTarget = this;
    }
});
$('.cit-pickup .se-body').droppable({
    accept: ".cit-pickup-row",
    drop: function(event, ui){
        $('.cit-pickup-table-body').append($(dragTarget));
        $(dragTarget).css({
            "position": "static"
        });
    }
});
$('.modal-droppable-area').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var droppableArea = $( this ).find('.droppable-content');
        $( this ).find('.droppable-content-info').hide();
        $(dragTarget).appendTo($(droppableArea));
        $(dragTarget).css({
            "position": "static",
            "background-color": "white",
            "margin": "5px",
            "border": "2px solid gray"
        });
        // "Reactivating" draggable element, and refounding dragTarget element to drag and drop elements back to CIT-Pickup table
        $( this ).find('.cit-pickup-row').draggable({
            drag: function(event, ui){
                window.dragTarget = this;
                $( this ).css({
                    "position": "relative",
                    "margin": "0",
                    "border": "none",
                    "border-bottom": "1px solid #dfdfdf"
                })
            }
        });
    }
})
})
```

И событие `onclick` не срабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Можно попробовать делегировать обработку родительскому контейнеру, повесить обработчик на него, а event.target покажет где был клик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что запись

```
$('.bank-deposit-row').on('click', function() {});
```

вешает событие на *существующие* элементы.

Для того чтобы работали события на *создаваемых* элементах вам необходимо [делегировать события](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation) ([jQuery](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On#.D0.9F.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.28.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_selector.29)).

Например так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bank-deposit-row', function() {});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает)