# Ajax обновление блока из которого идет сам вызов

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть ajax запрос на option-ы

```
$('input[type=\'checkbox\']').on('click', function() {
$(".products-subcategories").append(loadercircle);
$('#catalog-sort-form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(data) {
        $('.wrapper-whitening, #floatingCirclesG').hide();
        $('.catalog-items-wrapper').replaceWith($(data).find('.catalog-items-wrapper'));
        $('.catalog-bottom').replaceWith($(data).find('.catalog-bottom'));
        $('.mobile-sort-bottom').replaceWith($(data).find('.mobile-sort-bottom'));
    }
});});
```

Но так же, после подгрузки нужных нам объектов, должны обновляться с этой же страницы div-ы, в которых находятся сами options (на этой странице, с которой мы берем данные по submit, этих options больше )
Проблема следующая - если я добавляю

```
$('#categorie').replaceWith($(data).find('#categorie'));
$('#brand-block').replaceWith($(data).find('#brand-block'));
```

и обновляю этот блок с опциями - ajax срабатывает только единожды.
Чего мне не хватает, как сделать, чтобы ajax срабатывал по обновленному блоку с options?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему onclick не срабатывает на динамическом элементе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719796/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-onclick-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: спасибо за ссылку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719796/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-onclick-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5) вопросу, проблема решена делегированием событий

```
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type=\'checkbox\']', function() {});
```

Comment: на весь уж документ вешать-то не надо. найдите ближайшего кандидата по дереву DOM вверх